# If I have a direct reference to a google app engine Property object, how do I get() or set() upon it?

Tags: google-app-engine

Assume I have a Model class called Bird and a instance of Bird called pigeon. I know I can get all the Properties of Pigeon (or bird) using

```
properties = pigeon.properties() #Note, Bird.properties() would also work
```

This returns me a dictionary where the keys are strings that match the name I gave said properties in birds, and the value are actual Property objects. My question is, how do I get or set the value using said property objects. I wish to do this because I want to  allow a client to dynamically specify as strings:

1) the key to a Model object

2) a property of said Model object

3) and a value that the afformentioned Property of said Model object might take on

So clearly, I need to first get the Model object, then determine whether said Property exist, and finally get or set it somehow? Is this possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with [App Engine Console](http://con.appspot.com), which is great for testing and experimenting.  It looks to me like you want to use `__set__`, with the first argument being your model instance, and the second being the new value.  Next you need to `put()` the instance as usual.

Here is the console session to make it clearer.  (Have I mentioned how App Engine Console is awesome?)

```
>>> from google.appengine.ext import db
>>> class Bird(db.Model):
...   name = db.StringProperty()
...   can_fly = db.BooleanProperty()
... 
>>> def summarize():
...   for name in ('Pesto', 'Bobby'):
...     count = Bird.all().filter('name =', name).count()
...     print 'I found %d birds named %s' % (count, name)
...
>>> summarize()
I found 0 birds named Pesto
I found 0 birds named Bobby
>>> pigeon = Bird(name='Pesto', can_fly=True)
>>> pigeon.put()
datastore_types.Key.from_path('Bird', 41015L, _app=u'con')
>>> summarize()
I found 1 birds named Pesto
I found 0 birds named Bobby
>>> props = pigeon.properties()
>>> props
{'can_fly': <google.appengine.ext.db.BooleanProperty object at 0x46ddd1cc3ddb2268>, 'name': <google.appengine.ext.db.StringProperty object at 0x46ddd1cc3ddb2fe8>}
>>> prop = props['name']
>>> prop
<google.appengine.ext.db.StringProperty object at 0x46ddd1cc3ddb2a68>
>>> prop.__set__(pigeon, 'Bobby')
>>> pigeon.name
'Bobby'
>>> pigeon.put()
datastore_types.Key.from_path('Bird', 41015L, _app=u'con')
>>> summarize()
I found 0 birds named Pesto
I found 1 birds named Bobby
>>> bobby = Bird.all().filter('name =', 'Bobby').fetch(1)[0]
>>> bobby.name
u'Bobby'
```

If you try the online console demo yourself, be sure to delete my old instances first, as we all share the same data store.

Comment: This is exactly right. For more details on why it works like this, check out Raymond Hettinger's excellent "How to guide for descriptors": http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm